# Metadata point for SPL-token

Tags: mpl-token-metadata

Does anyone have a TS file that I can have that creates a metadata pointer for a token where the address is already known.

Almost every exampel I find also creates the token, but I need it to just create the metadata.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The metadata pointer must be initialized *before* the base mint is initialized, so it's not possible to add the pointer afterwards.

It's a bit tougher to digest, but there's an example doing it in the JS tests at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/8c177be2916da6f81a506c99f17e41e1f7c99d77/token/js/test/e2e-2022/metadataPointer.test.ts#L33:

```
        mint = Keypair.generate();
        metadataAddress = PublicKey.unique();

        const mintLen = getMintLen(EXTENSIONS);
        const lamports = await connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(mintLen);

        const transaction = new Transaction().add(
            SystemProgram.createAccount({
                fromPubkey: payer.publicKey,
                newAccountPubkey: mint.publicKey,
                space: mintLen,
                lamports,
                programId: TEST_PROGRAM_ID,
            }),
            createInitializeMetadataPointerInstruction(
                mint.publicKey,
                mintAuthority.publicKey,
                metadataAddress,
                TEST_PROGRAM_ID
            ),
            createInitializeMintInstruction(
                mint.publicKey,
                TEST_TOKEN_DECIMALS,
                mintAuthority.publicKey,
                null,
                TEST_PROGRAM_ID
            )
        );

        await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction, [payer, mint], undefined);
```